# Recursive menu with product count

Tags: php, recursion, menu, count, product

I want to create a recursive menu with the product totals included, however I am stuck now because I already rendered the Topmenu however i cant find another way to do it.

I dont want to use alot of MySQL Queries because it can make my site very slow.

The code i am using:

```
require 'db.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(c.category_id) AS count, c. category_id, c.parent_id, cd.name, p.product_id FROM category c
    LEFT JOIN category_description AS cd ON (cd.category_id=c.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN product_to_category AS ptc ON (ptc.category_id=c.category_id)
    LEFT JOIN product AS P ON (p.product_id=ptc.product_id) 
    GROUP BY c.category_id    
    ORDER BY c.parent_id,cd.name") or die (mysql_error()); 

$menuData = array( 'items' => array(), 'parents' => array() );

while ($menuItem = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $menuData['items'][$menuItem['category_id']] = $menuItem;
    $menuData['parents'][$menuItem['parent_id']][] = $menuItem['category_id'];
}

function buildMenu($parentId, $menuData) {
    $html = '';
    if (isset($menuData['parents'][$parentId]))
    {
        $html = '<ul>';

        foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) {
            $iCount  = ($menuData['items'][$itemId]['product_id'] != NULL) ? $menuData['items'][$itemId]['count'] : '0';

            $html   .= '<li>' . $menuData['items'][$itemId]['name'] . ' (' . $iCount . ') ';
            $html   .= buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);
            $html   .= '</li>';
        }

        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    return $html;
}
echo buildMenu(0, $menuData);
```

The expected output:

```
Dell (1)
--Computer(1)
---DataCable(1)
----Extra Sub (0)
```

Current output:

```
Dell (0)
--Computer(0)
---DataCable(1)
----Extra Sub (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your query returns wrong result. Use 
`print '<pre>';print_r($menuData);print '</pre>';` before calling buildMenu() function and see whether query returns right data or not.

Comment: I get the count for each category correct, but my problem is that it renders the TopCat First, and goes down from there. 

So when I go down i can never get the count of the top-category.
Will i need another recursive function that counts everything first?
Or what is the best practise for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this should get you closer to the right direction:

```
foreach ($menuData['parents'][$parentId] as $itemId) {
    $menu = buildMenu($itemId, $menuData);
    $item = $menuData['items'][$itemId];
    $iCount  = ($item['product_id'] != NULL) ? $item['count'] : '0';
    $menuData['items'][$parentId]['count'] += $iCount;
    $html   .= '<li>' . $item['name'] . ' (' . $iCount . ') ';
    $html   .= $menu
    $html   .= '</li>';
}
```

By re-ordering and then adding the current item's count to the parent item's count, you can make sure that when you output iCount, it will include all of the children's counts as well.

I also used a temporary variable for `$menuData['items'][$itemId]`. Because you're only doing three array lookups on that $menuData, it might not be substantially more efficient, but it is much easier to read.